# If $\mu>1$, $\int_a^\infty f dx $ converges absolutely and if $\mu=1$ and $A\neq 0$,$\int_a^\infty f dx $ diverges

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

> If $f(x)$ is continuous for $f(x)\geq a$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty} x^\mu f(x)=A$, then prove the following
>
> 1. if $\mu>1$, $\int_a^\infty f dx $ converges absolutely
> 2. if $\mu=1$ and $A\neq 0$,$\int_a^\infty f dx $ diverges
>
> Considering $\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2}$ and  $\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{x \ln{x}}$ state what will be the concusion in second case if $A=0$.

As $$\lim_{x\to \infty} x^\mu f(x)=A$$

$$\implies \lim_{x\to \infty} x^\mu |f(x)|=|A|$$
$$\implies |A|-\epsilon <x^\mu |f(x)|<|A|+\epsilon, \text{for} M>0, \forall x\geq A$$
$$\implies |f(x)|<(|A|+\epsilon)x^{-\mu} , \text{for} M>0, \forall x\geq A$$

As $$\int_M^\infty \frac{dx}{x^\mu}$$ converges if $\mu>1$, then by comparison test,
$$\int_M^\infty |f(x)|dx$$ converges.

Please help me.

Comment: Do you mean $\mu \to \infty$?

Comment: No no $\mu$ is not so

Comment: I'm confused what $n$ is.  Is $n$ supposed to be $x$?

Comment: Yes, I have corrected, thanks

Answer (score 1):

For the second question. Assume that $A<0$, then for large $M>0$, $f(x)<0$ for all $x\geq M$. Assume further that $M>0$ is such that $xf(x)-A<-A/2$, then $f(x)<(A/2)x^{-1}$ and we have $(A/2)\displaystyle\int_{M}^{\infty}x^{-1}dx=-\infty$, so $\displaystyle\int_{M}^{\infty}f(x)dx=-\infty$.

For the third part, $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}x\cdot\dfrac{1}{x^{2}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{1}{x}=0$ but $\displaystyle\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{x^{2}}dx=1<\infty$, also that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}x\cdot\dfrac{1}{x\log x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{1}{\log x}=0$ but $\displaystyle\int_{2}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{x\log x}dx=\log(\log x)\bigg|_{x=2}^{\infty}=\infty$.

Comment: Thanks. Please solve the 3rd part also.

Comment: Where is the third part?

Comment: Considering $\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2}$ and  $\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{x \ln{x}}$ state what will be the concusion in second case if $A=0$.